# Not able to run an Azure Web Job Error: Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException: Token request failed

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, sharepoint-online

We have an Azure Web Job that runs weekly. But of late it has not been running. When we checked the  logs this is what we get

```
    [04/28/2017 16:32:38 > e85929: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing

[04/28/2017 16:32:40 > e85929: SYS INFO] Run script 'EmailSchedulerJob.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'

[04/28/2017 16:32:40 > e85929: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

[04/28/2017 16:32:40 > e85929: INFO] Site URL is https://name.sharepoint.com

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: INFO] Error: Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException: Token request failed. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: INFO]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: INFO]    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2WebRequest.GetResponse()

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: INFO]    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: INFO]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: INFO]    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: INFO]    at EmailSchedulerJob.TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(String targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm)

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: INFO]    at EmailSchedulerJob.Program.Main(String[] args)

[04/28/2017 16:32:41 > e85929: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

I thought it was something to do with the code. We published multiple versions of this project but still getting the same Issue. The code performs a lookup on a SharePoint list.

We also tried looking at the Publish Settings file. It appears to be slightly different with a link to the Control Panel

```
<publishData><publishProfile profileName="TestAppName - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" publishUrl="testappname.scm.azurewebsites.net:443" msdeploySite="estAppName" userName="$TestAppName" userPWD="" destinationAppUrl="http://appname.azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites"><databases /></publishProfile><publishProfile profileName="TestAppName - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod-sn1-031.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot" ftpPassiveMode="True" userName="TestAppName\$TestAppName" userPWD="" destinationAppUrl="http://testappname.azurewebsites.net" SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com" webSystem="WebSites"><databases /></publishProfile></publishData>
```

Any suggestions on how this can be resolved would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Code for Initializing the web job
webjob-publish-settings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "EmailSchedulerJob",
  "startTime": "2016-05-30T00:00:00-05:00",
  "endTime": null,
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Week",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value=""/>
    <add key="ClientSecret" value=""/>
    <add key="DaysLeftToRemind" value="3"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <!--Used by SharePoint Add-in-->
        <binding name="secureBinding">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Cache">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Cache" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="D:\home\LogFiles\NetTracing\network.log"
           traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Code for connecting to SharePoint

```
string sharepointSiteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SPSiteUrl");
                string emailUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EmailUserName"); 
                string emailPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("EmailPassword");
                Uri sharepointSiteUri = new Uri(sharepointSiteUrl);

                Console.WriteLine("Site URL is " + sharepointSiteUrl);

                string appRealm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(sharepointSiteUri);
                string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, sharepointSiteUri.Authority, appRealm).AccessToken;
```

**Update**

Since there is a possibility that the Client Secret Key might have expired we generated a new key and now when we run the Web Job we get this error on the logs-
 **Error: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.**

Current Log File

```
[05/01/2017 20:07:19 > 56e469: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing

    [05/01/2017 20:07:19 > 56e469: SYS INFO] Run script 'EmailSchedulerJob.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'

    [05/01/2017 20:07:19 > 56e469: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running

    [05/01/2017 20:07:20 > 56e469: INFO] Site URL is https://sohodragon.sharepoint.com

    [05/01/2017 20:07:20 > 56e469: INFO] Inside hostClientContext

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO] Error: Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at EmailSchedulerCommon.Code.Helpers.SharePointHelpers.GetListItemsByViewName(ClientContext ctx, String listName, String viewName)

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at EmailSchedulerCommon.Code.Business.HolidayManager.GetUpcomingHolidays(ClientContext ctx)

    [05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: INFO]    at EmailSchedulerJob.Program.Main(String[] args)

[05/01/2017 20:07:21 > 56e469: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

Comment: Could the client secret have expired?

Comment: @juunas I am not sure. How do I check to see whether it is expired?

Comment: This article explains how to renew secrets, but also shows how to check existing ones: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn726681.aspx.

Comment: check if AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage have proper AccountName and AccountKeys

Comment: @juunas I followed the article but the output file did not contain the client secret key for the App Service in Azure. So, I am still not sure whether it is expired or not.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan Should I be checking this in the old portal or the new one?

Comment: check in new portal

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I clicked on Web Jobs under App Services, that shows the list of web jobs. And I clicked on Application Settings, that shows the client ID, client secret ID etc. Is this what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, there should be 2 additional settings as I mentioned above

Comment: @KarthikGanesan There are fields for EmailUsername and Password that appear to be correct.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I would highly appreciate if you could provide an answer (possible solutions) with some screenshots.

Comment: @user3402248 it should be your connection string setting check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started apart from your connection string to perform crud operations Webjob need 2 additional connection string with these names

Comment: @KarthikGanesan In the app.config file and the web.config file, I don't have a connection string.

Comment: Could you provide some core code about init your webjob and code for accessing SharePoint? Since your webjob could work before and the response status code is 401, I assumed that you could try to use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture HTTP traces on your local side.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT As requested, I have updated my post with the code.

Comment: @juunas I have generated a new clientsecret key and I am getting an Error Message Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue has been fixed. Deleted the old app file. Deployed and re-added a new app file with a new key.